Duplicate - older post doesn’t have an answer
I reviewed a post written 8 yrs and 8 months ago. The post seemed familiar to me, and that was because I’ve seen the same question before. I searched it and marked it as a duplicate, but now I realized that the post that has an answer was written later than the post, which was written 8 yrs and 7 months ago.
What should I do? Should I still mark it as a duplicate, because other post(s) already has an answer? Again, does the ‘duplicate’ mean that ‘other question has an answer’, or ‘it has been asked before?’

This has been discussed before - see here, here, and here. Past discussion seems to have coalesced around "mark as duplicate and point towards the best answer to the underlying question".

Ironically, this question is similar to: Original post marked as duplicate.

Assuming that the new question is marked as a duplicate, if you have an answer that provides analysis lacking in the older duplicate question, you may wish to add your answer to the older question.  This way, when the OP of the new question visits the older question, they will see your answer.  In fact, I once did this when the newer question had been mis-characterized as a duplicate.  I crafted an answer to the new question, added it to the older question, and explained that I was doing so because of the mis-characterization.
